# How to control Microsoft Speech Recognition app?

Tags: c#, python, speech-recognition

I want to know if it's possible to control "Microsoft Speech Recognition" using c#.

[image]
<sub>(source: [yfrog.com](http://a.yfrog.com/img191/8859/enable.png))</sub>

Is it possible, for instance, to simulate the click on "On: Listen to everything I say" programmatically using c# or python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRobert had the right idea.

If you were using C++, then you would call [ISpRecognizer::SetRecoState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718870(v=VS.85).aspx)([SPRST_ACTIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717269(v=VS.85).aspx)), and then, if you're running on Windows 7, QI the ISpRecognizer for ISpRecognizer3 and call [ISpRecognizer3::SetActiveCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413268(v=VS.85).aspx)(NULL) to force the recognizer into the ON state.

But, since you're using C#, you should use [System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer(v=VS.100).aspx) and set the [State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.state(v=VS.100).aspx) property to Listening.  (Note that this will not, as far as I know, switch from Sleep to On.)

Comment: thanks m8

I also have some c++ code :) so I can do what you told ^^

Comment: There's no direct API, but the UI has an HWND (whose class you can discover with Spy++ or Inspect), and you can minimize it by posting a WM_SYSCOMMAND message with WParam == SC_MINIMIZE.

Answer (score -1):

Here's Microsoft's [Speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720151%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#APIOverview) documentation, and an 
[example in Python](http://surguy.net/articles/speechrecognition.xml).

Comment: m8, please read my question! I don't want to do the Speech Recognition part. I want to simulate the click on the button ON programmatically!